# How to create zone object momentjs or how to get browser timezone name?

Tags: browser, namespaces, timezone, momentjs

http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/zone-object/
 I want to read my browser timezone name like "Sri jayawardenapura","Bangkok"..

Answer (score 0):

Determining the localized name (English or otherwise) of current time zone is not a supported feature of moment-timezone.

Comment: thanks..do we any other way to achieve timezone Name??

Comment: Not easily, no.  If you're looking for the time zone id, such as `America/Los_Angeles`, then you can use [jsTimeZoneDetect](http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/), and similar functionality is being worked on for a future-release of moment-timezone.  But if you're looking for a human-readable locale-specific display name, that's the job of [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/), and I know of no JavaScript implementtions that include the very large time zone portions of that data set.